# Can I store a pair of keys on iOS secure element?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-pair

I would like to know if I can use the iPhone's secure element to store a pair of keys. I need to store them in the safest emplacement, and I can't think of a better one than the secure element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest place to store pair of keys is keychain store. You can use a keychain wrapper to do this. I recommend to use this wrapper: [here is the link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore)

Comment: Thank you Mustafa for your answer. It would have been perfect if the secure element was accessible, but at the same time I wasn't expecting it to be the case.